# Response of ajax request is different on my local environment and my live server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, responsetext

In my local environment my ajax response is a json object as expected which only contains the objects and their value pairs I requested from an sql database, but once uploaded to hostgator the response is much larger and my object can only be found in the responseText value of the response object.

The responseText property doesn't exist in my local environment so accessing it directly in my live environment would put my local and live code out of sync and likely cause problems when doing updates plus responseText is a string containing my objects preceded by // making it difficult to access without parsing and type casting.

I was going to post the objects but they don't format well unless I recreate them and the response from the hostgator sever is too large to recreate. Instead here is how my php script is returning the sql data.

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.constant('DB_HOST').';dbname='.constant('DB_NAME').';charset=utf8', constant('DB_USER'), constant('DB_PW'));

    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT `index`, Todays_Date, First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Telephone, Position  FROM application');
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $row_count = count($result);

    if($row_count > 0){
        echo json_encode($result);
    }else{
        echo "No records found.";
    }

    // ajax call update 
    var listAjax = function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/listAll.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
    }).done(function(data) {
        buildList(data);
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to return my json object from php? or maybe this is a common problem I haven't ran into. Let me know if need to see anything else from the response object. Thanks for any help.

Update: Added ajax code. Did see that the longer response from server with response text did not come through with the commented out fail, but it does have a status 200. Tried to post images of it but stack overflow won't let me. Here is a link to a photo of the response output: 
http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah114/Dakota_Hipp/IMG_1158_zps32xytuqx.png

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there is no errors being reported from the AJAX call? When the same thing happened to me, I used to always get an error. Also it might be good to post a bit of the data; not a lot, but just enough.

Comment: added a link to the console output of the response and the ajax call. weird thing is it is working fine on my computer and wamp but not on a hosted server.

Comment: Well, we need to make sure the hosted server doesn't have the problem, so keep testing from that location. I want you to try this, and just humor me. Inside your AJAX object, below data: {}, I want you to add two properties. `success: function(data) { alert("I have data"); },` AND `error: function(obj) { alert("Error"+obj); }`. This should allow you to debug and determine where an error is coming from. Have you tried viewing the output (Via URL) and see if there is any errors that are shown? (Should be easier than using AJAX objects to find the error)

Comment: changed ajax data type to text and am getting a response of // + valid json. It looks like the response has // added to it making it invalid json causing the ajax call to fail when ajax data type is json even with status 200. 

can't find out why // would be added.

Comment: On production server my ajax call is hitting fail with status 200. I found on other help pages a status 200 fail could be from invalid json being returned. Once I changed ajax data type to text I am hitting the .done of ajax and getting my data returned as text. The text looks like valid json but is prefixed with //

Comment: `//` wouldn't be added from `encode_json()`. Check the page where you are requesting data from `url: "api/listAll.php",` and check to see if there are any `//` that are being displayed. That is the only thing I can think of. The `//` is just out of place somewhere.

Comment: I have no idea. it is really weird. I've commented out various lines to see if that will stop the //, took off json encode, and even just echoed out test strings and everything is being prefixed with //

Comment: wow so after echoing stuff out at every line to see where the // started. it looks like it was from my config file I had my local info commented out to make updating on the server easier, some out it was echoing the slashes.

    // <?php
    // define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    // define("DB_NAME", "notreal");
    // define("DB_USER", "notreal");
    // define("DB_PW", "notreal");
    // ?>

if you could have found that out I'd be scared. Anyways thank you man! @Twister1002

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it was able to fix the error! So you are getting valid JSON now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Discussions:

In the image shown, there is an `//` being added to the beginning of your echoed data which is making your JSON invalid. You need to backtrace through your included files inside your requested URL: `url: "api/listAll.php"` and remove the `//` to make your JSON valid again.